# What user permissions are needed to execute WMI calls in LAN from a .NET application on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, wmi, wmi-query

Aim:        In MVC 5 / C# I am trying to use WMI to read whether certain processes are running on machines on my LAN (and then start / stop them by users checking / unchecking checkbox controls).
When the application is run in the IIS hosted environment we get no results - all the checkboxes that show processes running are unchecked, but we know this is incorrect. Correct results are returned when the same code is executed in the application from Visual Studio.
On IIS the app pool for the application is running under ApplicationPoolIdentity.

I would be grateful for any help with this.

Here is the method that determines whether relevant processes are running:

```
    public static List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> GetNodeProcesses(string NetworkName, List<Application> apps, string NodeReply)
    {
    //Get the list of processes and assign false to each process
    List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, bool>>();
    if (NodeReply == "success")
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < apps.Count; i++)
    {
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(apps[i].ProcessName, false));

//Iterate through processes that are running and check each process for a match in the list variable, if a match is found assign true to the item in the list variable
                        try
                        {
                            ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
                            connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                            connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
                            ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", NetworkName), connOptions);
                            manScope.Connect();

                            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manScope, new SelectQuery("select Name from Win32_Process")))
                            {
                                foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
                                {
                                    string process = mo["Name"].ToString();
                                    if (apps.Any(p => p.ProcessName == process))
                                    {
                                        list.Remove(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(process, false));
                                        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>(process, true));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>("An error occurred getting processes running on " + NetworkName + ":" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, false));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    { list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, bool>("", false)); }

                    return list;
                }
```